# Is this safe? eval or new Function for simple arithmetic expression

Tags: javascript, regex, eval

I have heard so many bad things about eval that I've never even tried to use it. However today I have a situation where it seems to be the right answer.

I need a script that can do simple calculations by combining variables. For example, if value=5 and max=8, I want to evaluate value*100/max. Both the values and the formulas will be retrieved from external sources, which is why I am concerned with eval.

I have set up a jsfiddle demo with some sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/6yzgA/

The values are converted to numbers using parseFloat, so I believe I'm pretty safe here. The characters in the formula are matched again this regular expression:

```
regex=/[^0-9\.+-\/*<>!=&()]/, // allows numbers (including decimal), operations, comparison
```

My questions:

- Does my regex filter protect me from any attack?
- Is there any reason to use eval vs. new Function in this case?
- Is there another, safer way to evaluate formulas?

Answer (score 3):

Since you aren't sending anything sending anything to your server, or using anything on anyone else's system, the worst that can happen is that the user crashes his own browser, nothing more. There is nothing unsafe about using `eval` here, since everything happens user-side.

Comment: +1 I concur...`eval` is more dangerous in a server-side language, like PHP. Not as big of a deal on a client-side language, like Javascript.

Comment: I used input fields for the demo, but as I said in the question the values and formulas actually come from external sources. I'm worried that a malicious source might push an unsafe formula (script tag or onload event or other stuff I cannot imagine)

Comment: @Travesty3 `eval` could be also dangerous on client-side and used for Cross Site Scripting. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_site_scripting Yet, in this example it's completely safe, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Escaping and **preventing anything on the client-side doesn't make sense** at all. User can alter any piece of JS code and run it just as easy as I can change the jsfiddle you posted. Trust me, it's just that simple and you cannot rely on the client-side security.

If you remember to escape input fields on the server-side it's nothing to be worried about. There are plenty of functions for that by default, depending on which language you're using.

If user wants to type in `<script>haxx(l33t);</script>` - let him do it. Just remember to escape special characters so you'll have `&lt;script&gt;haxx(l33t);&lt;/script&gt;`.

Comment: I am not worried about users harming themselves, rather about getting hurt by an external source (cf. my question and my comment on @Kolink's answer). Escaping special characters sounds like a great idea, the issue is that it'll break my validation expressions (greater than, less than).

Comment: True that. Therefore you'll probably have to formulate your custom regexps and test them thoroughly.